# Running python scripts from within java class Android Studio

Tags: python, android

I want to integrate python with my android app. What I want is:
I will write a python script and I will put it somewhere in my project folder. And I should be able to call that script from my activity class .java file.
In simple words, I want to build my complete app in Android Studio only but I want to use python for some parts of my code.

I know of only one thing that perfectly fits this criteria and that's "Chaquopy" but I don't want to use Chaquopy.

Can you please suggest something else?
Thank you

Comment: What is it about Chaquopy that doesn't suit your requirements?  It would probably help to understand your requirements.

Comment: Chaquopy is the best suited for my case @Ryan M but I have to buy a license for using it and I just develop apps for fun, free of cost. So I want an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [flask](http://flask.palletsprojects.com/) and have an endpoint like so:

```
@app.rooute('/data', methods=['GET'])
def meth():
   # python code here
   return make_response(jsonify({'results': ret}), 200)
```

I've actually set up an endpoint for you to use [here](https://hd1-martin.herokuapp.com) that takes a png file, uses pillow to resize it to 1200 pixels and returns the new png.

Your task is now to display the PNG however you would in Java.

EDIT: There are many, many approaches to read data from the HTTP endpoint in Java, one is given below, using okhttp:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder().url("https://hd1-martin.herokuapp.com/data").build();
Response rawResponse = new OkHttpClient().newCall(request).execute();
byte[] response = rawResponse.body().bytes();
```

This is the limit of my expertise, I'm now leaving the rest in your capable hands to get the new image to display in Android, with the following hint... I suspect you're going to be looking at writing the bytes -- in response in the snippet -- to a file and loading it into an Android ImageView.

Hope that helps.

Comment: would you be kind enough to tell me this in detail. I don't have even a vaguest idea about this. Can you tell me all steps in detail. Like what line should I add in build.gradle, what to import, where to put the code. Thank you.

Comment: How can I integrate it with Android Studio so that I can call the python method from anywhere in between my code. It should be there when I complete the app build and export it as an apk

Comment: Separate from android. Then use OkHttp to make the call. Should you need further assistance, let's get a chatroom started and handle it there

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216232/62440837

Comment: I am unable to chat there. It says you must have 20 reputation to chat here.

Comment: So can you please clarify the doubts here. Just give me a simple example of the complete process on how to successfully call the python method from my java code. And that method should get included in my apk when I build it so that it doesn't require anything else to run the apk. Thanks

Comment: Do you know how to make an HTTP call in Java?

Comment: No, I am afraid not

Comment: What is that url, what is it doing? And what is that file which contains the code @app.route.....anr where do I place it?

Comment: The url is supposed to be wherever your python stuff is running. And @app.route is supposed to be a flask application handling whatever you want python to handle.

Comment: Sorry I am asking a lot of questions but I am a complete newbie to Flask and JSon and this complete web development side. Suppose my flask application  is in  the directory  _app\src\main\flask_   then should I use the same url that you gave ```"https://martins-helper.herokuapp.com/data"``` . And how does it know the path of my flask application. And how does my flask application knows that it should respond to this particular url?

Comment: Let's take this to a chatroom, this does not seem effective, in the least.

Comment: I can't message in chatroom. It seems I don't have enough reputation points. It requires minimum 20, I have 5. That's alright. You helped me a lot, I will better do some research on my own now. You have shown me the path atleast. I will accept your answer. I will do a bit of research on flask and all and I will figure out. Thank you very much @hd1.

Comment: Np Martin, if you tell me what you need your python to do, I can set up a service for you to call, as needed

Comment: I will have a flask file like app\src\main\flask\example.py and my java file from where I am calling the flask file is app\src\main\java\main_activity.java . My python file will accept path of an image from phone's internal storage and pass it as a parameter to the python method. The python method will accept the path and resize that image to say 1200 x 1200 and save it as a new image.

Comment: But will it work in phone? Because I am developing an app in Android Studio and I want to use this in my app. I think Android Studio don't have a python interpreter by default. How will it execute the python file once it is made to run in Android device?

Comment: You're going to need to upload the file to the server do your modifications there and put the new file out as a response from python. Read the response back into Android using the OkHttp code I've provided and then save those bytes to an on-device file.

Comment: I will try that

Comment: How did it go, @Martin?

Comment: First of all sorry @hd1 I could not reply. I searched and learned a bit about flask and I have understood what you were trying to tell me. What I did was : 1) I created a flask_server.py file like this : `import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def handle_request():
    return "Flask Server & Android are Working Successfully"

app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True)`                                                    And in android studio I used okhttp as you said to connect to the server. In my app (for testing  purpose

Comment: ) I am entering the IPV4 address from my PC and the port number and then as I click connect I should get the message "Flask Server & Android are Working Successfully" if it gets connected successfully otherwise "Failed to Connect to Server" will be displayed. I connected my PC and phone via hotspot and then I started my flask sever, entered the IPV4 address of my PC (by using ipconfig) and port number in my app but when I press connect, it says "Failed to Connect to Server". If I copy the url that I am generating in my app (which is supposed to be the server address) and paste it in

Comment: my PC browser then it is running perfectly. I don't know where the problem is. What should I do? I followed a tutorial from Medium for this.

Comment: If I copy the url from my app and paste it in my phone's browser then also it is working perfectly. But not in my app, it shows same message "Failed to Connect to Server"